# Error with 2 pagination's on same Webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, will-paginate

I am not a ruby on rails programmer but i have gotten quite far with adding a second results table to my page.

the problem that i have is that the Pagination is messed up.

When it is first loaded. everything looks right. but when you click on another page number it changes the page on second table as well. plus adds a copy of the second table as like a 3rd table to the page.

i have screan shots.

**Original page loads**
[Orignial when page loads http://www.digihaul.com/1.png](http://www.digihaul.com/1.png)

**Once a page is selected**

## [Once a page is selected http://www.digihaul.com/2.png](http://www.digihaul.com/2.png)

here is my View

```
.row-fluid#load_results_table
  .span12
    - if resultss.empty?
      =render partial: 'no_results', locals: {search: search}
    - else
      %h1.page-header Premium Loads
      %p= "These are our loads we are offering. We guarentee 100% payment on these loads"
    %table.table.search_results.table-condensed.table-bordered.table-striped.sortable{:id => "#{searches.search_type.pluralize}"}
      %thead
        %tr.search_header
          %th= sortable_load "origin"
          %th= sortable_load "dest"
          %th= sortable_load "pickup"
          %th= sortable_load "delivery"
          %th= sortable_load "ltl"
          %th= sortable_load "equipment_id", "Equipment"
          %th= sortable_load "weight"
          %th= sortable_load "length"
          %th= sortable_load "rate"
          -unless @searches.origin.blank?
            %th Estimated Deadhead Miles
          %th Actions
      %tbody
        - resultss.each do |result|
          %tr{:class => "#{searches.search_type}_view", :id => "#{result['id']}" }
            %td= Location.to_cs(result.origin)
            %td= Location.to_cs(result.dest)
            %td= format_date(result.pickup)
            %td= format_date(result.delivery)
            %td= full_or_par(result.ltl)
            %td= result.equipment_id ? Equipment.to_equipment_name(result.equipment_id) : ""
            %td= result.weight
            %td= result.length
            %td= result.rate
            -unless @searches.origin.blank?
              %td= Location.distance_between(@searches.origin.coords, result['origin'])
            %td
              .btn-group
                %a.btn.btn-info{ :href => "/#{searches.search_type.pluralize}/#{result['id']}" } Show
                %a.btn{ :href => "javascript:void(0)", :class => "save", user_id: @searches.user_id, :id => result['id']} Save
                %a.btn.btn-primary{ :href => "javascript:void(0)", :class => "cover_link", :user_id=> @searches.user_id } Cover 
    = will_paginate resultss, :renderer => BootstrapPagination::Rails
.row-fluid#load_results_table
  .span12
    - if results.empty?
      =render partial: 'no_results', locals: {search: search}
    - else
      %h1.page-header Search Results
      - if results.count > 1000
        %p= "Your search yielded many #{search.search_type.pluralize}"
      - else
        %p= "Your search yielded #{results.count} #{search.search_type.pluralize}"
      =render partial: 'header_buttons', locals: {search: search}
      %br
      = will_paginate results, :renderer => BootstrapPagination::Rails, id: "first_pagination"
      %table.table.search_results.table-condensed.table-bordered.table-striped.sortable{:id => "#{search.search_type.pluralize}"}
        %thead
          %tr.search_header
            %th= sortable_load "origin"
            %th= sortable_load "dest"
            %th= sortable_load "pickup"
            %th= sortable_load "delivery"
            %th= sortable_load "ltl"
            %th= sortable_load "equipment_id", "Equipment"
            %th= sortable_load "weight"
            %th= sortable_load "length"
            %th= sortable_load "rate"
            -unless @search.origin.blank?
              %th Estimated Deadhead Miles
            %th Actions
        %tbody
          - results.each do |result|
            %tr{:class => "#{search.search_type}_view", :id => "#{result['id']}" }
              %td= Location.to_cs(result.origin)
              %td= Location.to_cs(result.dest)
              %td= format_date(result.pickup)
              %td= format_date(result.delivery)
              %td= full_or_par(result.ltl)
              %td= result.equipment_id ? Equipment.to_equipment_name(result.equipment_id) : ""
              %td= result.weight
              %td= result.length
              %td= result.rate
              -unless @search.origin.blank?
                %td= Location.distance_between(@search.origin.coords, result['origin'])
              %td
                .btn-group
                  %a.btn.btn-info{ :href => "/#{search.search_type.pluralize}/#{result['id']}" } Show
                  %a.btn{ :href => "javascript:void(0)", :class => "save", user_id: @search.user_id, :id => result['id']} Save
                  %a.btn.btn-primary{ :href => "javascript:void(0)", :class => "cover_link", :user_id=> @search.user_id } Cover 
      = will_paginate results, :renderer => BootstrapPagination::Rails
```

Controller:

```
  def show
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
    @searches = Search.find(params[:id])
    @results = @search.search(params[:page])
    @resultss = @searches.searches(params[:page])
    @search.update_attribute(:results, @results.count)
    @searches.update_attribute(:resultss, @resultss.count)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.js {render "results"}
      format.js {render "resultss"}
    end
  end
```

Model (minimized the query)

```
  def search(page)
    where = []
    where << PrepareSearch.states("dest", self.dest_states) unless self.dest_states.blank?
    if self.search_type == 'load'
      select = "loads.id, origin, dest, pickup, delivery, ltl, equipment_id, weight, length, rate"
      where << PrepareSearch.date('pickup', self.pickup, self.pickup_operator) unless self.pickup.blank?
    elsif self.search_type == 'truck'
      select = "trucks.id, origin, dest, available, expiration, equipment_id, comments"
      where << PrepareSearch.date('available',self.available,self.available_operator) unless self.available.blank?
    end
    where = where.join(' AND ')
    order = self.order_by ? self.order_by + " desc" : ""
    limit = "LIMIT=200"
      Module.const_get(self.search_type.capitalize).where(where).select(select).limit(limit).order(order).page(page).per_page(20)
  end


  def searches(page)
    where = []
    where << PrepareSearch.states("dest", self.dest_states) unless self.dest_states.blank?
    if self.search_type == 'load'
      select = "loads.id, origin, dest, pickup, delivery, ltl, equipment_id, weight, length, rate"
      where << PrepareSearch.date('pickup', self.pickup, self.pickup_operator) unless self.pickup.blank?
    elsif self.search_type == 'truck'
      select = "trucks.id, origin, dest, available, expiration, equipment_id, comments"
      where << PrepareSearch.date('available',self.available,self.available_operator) unless self.available.blank?
    end
    where = where.join(' AND ')
    order = self.order_by ? self.order_by + " desc" : ""
    limit = "LIMIT=200"
      Hotload.where(where).select(select).limit(limit).order(order).page(page).per_page(5)
  end
```

Comment: Would it have something to do with: id: "first_pagination" being the same. if i change that will it break anything that i need to fix in javascript or anywhere

Comment: guess i will have to look into that.

Comment: you will either have to create and use a separate page key for the other table or go with ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax pagination is one way, as described in the comments, but the best way to handle it will be to change the `page` param for each pagination block

---

**param_name**

You can do this with [`Kaminari`](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) (I know you're using `will_paginate`) using the [`param_name`](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#general-configuration-options) argument. This basically sets the `param` each pagination block reads, allowing you to call them differenetly, thus controlling different sets of data:

```
<%= paginate collection, param_name: model.to_s %>
```

Having researched how to do this with `will_paginate`, it seems [you're able to use the `param_name` argument too](http://www.devinterface.com/blog/en/2011/08/tips-multiple-pagination-with-will_paginate/):

```
<%= will_paginate @products, param_name: 'products_page' %>
```

Comment: will this fix my duplication that i get as well?

Comment: when i select a page # on the pagination bar. it duplicates the second table as seen in the pictures above...

Comment: Hmmmm I see! Let me have a look for you

Comment: I added my model and my controller. i am still having issues incorporating this solution. if you could take a look and give me a pointer on what i need to change to get it to work correctly would be great